# How to solve MIT Integration Bee $2023$: $\int_0^{100} \lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil dx$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So I was yet again looking through the homepage of Youtube when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/AJa9X_iUkAo) video by Michael Penn which was asking us this question from the $2023$ MIT Integration Bee:$$\text{Integrate: }\int_0^{100}\lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil dx$$Which I thought that I might be able to do. Here is my attempt at solving the integral:$$\text{Integrate: }\int_0^{100}\lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil dx$$$$\sum_{n=0}^{99}\int_n^{n+1}\lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil dx$$$$\sum_{n=0}^{99}n^2+n\int_n^{n+1}xdx$$$$\sum_{n=0}^{99}n^2+n(\frac{x^2}{2}\|_n^{n+1})$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{99}2n^3+n^2+2n+1$$Or$$24671675$$
**My question**

---

Is the result that I have achieved correct, or what could I do to attain the correct solution/attain it more easily?

**Mistakes that I might have made**

---

1. Sums are pretty difficult for me, so I might have miscalculated a sum or something.
2. Representing integrals as sums incorrectly.

Comment: Well for what it's worth, your method is correct and if it were upto me , I'd do it the same way. As for the answer, you can always check it on Wolfram alpha or any CAS . If it matches then you're good to go.

Comment: I could not follow the step from $\sum_{n=0}^{99}\int_n^{n+1}\lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil dx$ to $\sum_{n=0}^{99}n^2+n\int_n^{n+1}xdx$. Just looking at the term for $n=1,$ I get $3$ in the first sum and $5/2$ in the second sum.

Comment: @DavidK I believe there should be a bracket. I mean $\sum_{n=0}^{99}n(n+1)\int_{n}^{n+1}x\,dx$

Comment: Did you mean to write $\sum_{n=0}^{99}(n^2+n)\int_n^{n+1}xdx$? If so, then that step is OK but I think there is an error further down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $I(n)=\displaystyle\int_n^{n+1}x^3dx=\frac{(n+1)^4-n^4}{4}=(n+\tfrac 12)(2n^2+2n\color{red}{+1})/2$

On the other hand

$\displaystyle\int_n^{n+1} \lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil dx=(n+\tfrac 12)(n^2+n)=I(n)-\color{red}{\tfrac 12(n+\tfrac 12)}=I(n)-\tfrac 12\int_n^{n+1}x\,dx$

It results that

$$\int_0^{100} \lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil dx=\int_0^{100}\big(x^3-\tfrac 12x\big)dx=\Bigg[\frac{x^4-x^2}4\Bigg]_0^{100}=\dfrac{10^8-10^4}4$$

Answer (score 4):

It's the correct idea. However,
$$
\int_n^{n+1}\lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil dx
=\int_n^{n+1}nx(n+1) = (n^2+n)\int_n^{n+1}x = (n^2+n)\left(\frac{(n+1)^2 - n^2}{2}\right)
$$
Simplifying, you should get
$$
\int_n^{n+1}\lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil dx
=(n^2+n)\left(\frac{(n+1)^2 - n^2}{2}\right)
=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{2} = n^3 + \frac{3n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{2}
$$
After summing, I get 24997500.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $$
\int_0^n\lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil d x=\frac{n(n+1)^2(n+2)}{4}
$$
Proof:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^n \lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil  d x & =\sum_{k=0}^n \int_{k=1}^{k+1}\lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil d x \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{k+1}^{k+1} k x(k+1) d x \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1) \int_k^{k+1} x d x \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_k^{k+1} \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1)(2 k+1)
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the formula for the sum of powers $1,2,3 $ of the first n natural numbers, we have

$$\int_0^n \lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil  d x = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^2+\frac{3}{2}\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{6}(2 n+1)+\frac{1}{4} n(n+1)= \frac{n(n+1)^2(n+2)}{4} $$

In particular,
$$
\int_0^{99} \lfloor x\rfloor x\lceil x\rceil  d x = \frac{\left.99(100)^2(101\right)}{4}=24997500 $$