# Monster floor integral from the $2023$ MIT Integration Finals: $\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\lfloor2^nx\rfloor}{3^n}\right)^2dx$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So I was looking through the homepage of Youtube to see if there were any math problems that I thought that I might be able to solve when I came across
this video by Maths$505$ asking how to evaluate this monster integral from the $2023$ MIT Integration Finals. This is the monster floor integral:[$$\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\lfloor2^nx\rfloor}{3^n}\right)^2dx$$](https://youtu.be/q3ZAhxnBG8Y)which I thought that I might be able to evaluate. Here is my attempt at evaluating the monster floor integral:

---

---

#### $$\text{Here's what I know}$$

---

---

1. From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4695240/how-to-solve-mit-integration-bee-2023-int-0100-lfloor-x-rfloor-x-lceil) question of mine, I know that $\lfloor x\rfloor$ can be represented as $x-1$, and that a sum $\left(\sum_{a=\operatorname{Var}[b]}^cd\right)^2$ is equivalent to $\sum_{a=\operatorname{Var}[b]}^cd^3$ (as long as $\operatorname{Var}[b]=1$), we can rewrite the integral as$$\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2^nx-1)^3}{27^n}\right)dx$$Which I realized that I was doing this wrong. I rewrote the integral as$$2\int_0^\frac12\left(\sum_{u\geq2}\dfrac{\lfloor2^{n+1}u\rfloor}{3^u3^{-1}}\right)^2du$$(substituting $x=2u$ and $dx=2du$)$$=18\int_0^\frac12\left(\sum_{u\geq2}\dfrac{\lfloor2^uu\rfloor}{3^u}+\dfrac{\lfloor2u\rfloor}{3}\right)^2du$$$$=18\int_0^\frac12\left(\sum_{u\geq1}\dfrac{2^uu}{3^n}\right)^2du$$Letting $u=t+\dfrac12$
   $$I=\int_0^\frac12+\int_\frac12^1\left(\sum_u\dfrac{\lfloor2^ut+2^{u-1}\rfloor}{3^n}\right)^2dt$$$$=\int_0^\frac12+\int_\frac12^1\left(\sum_u\dfrac{\lfloor2^ut\rfloor+2^{u-1}}{3^u}\right)^2dt$$$$=\int_0^\frac12+\int_\frac12^1\left(\sum_u\dfrac{\lfloor2^ut\rfloor}{3^u}+\sum_u\dfrac{2^u}{3^u}\right)^2dt$$Which can be rewritten as$$\int_0^\frac12+\int_\frac12^1\left(\left(\sum_u\dfrac{\lfloor2^ut\rfloor}{3^u}\right)^2+1+2\sum_u\dfrac{\lfloor2^ut\rfloor}{3^u}\right)dt$$$$=2\int_0^\frac12+\int_0^\frac121dt+2\int_0^\frac12\sum_u\dfrac{\lfloor2^ut\rfloor}{3^u}dt$$$$=\sum_{u\geq1}\int_0^\frac12\dfrac{\lfloor2^ut\rfloor}{3^u}dt$$$$=\sum_{u\geq1}\dfrac{1}{3^u}\int_0^\frac12\lfloor2^ut\rfloor dt$$
   Letting
   $$2^ut=x$$$$\implies2^udt=dx$$$$\implies dt=2^{-u}dx$$$$\implies I=\sum_{u\geq1}\dfrac1{3^u}\dfrac1{2^u}\int_0^{2^{u-1}}\lfloor x\rfloor dx$$$$=\sum_{u\geq1}\dfrac1{3^u2^u}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{u-1}-1}k$$$$=\sum_{u\geq1}\dfrac1{3^u2^u}\dfrac{\left(2^{u-1}-1\right)\left(2^{u-1}\right)}2$$$$=\dfrac12\sum_{u\geq1}\dfrac{2^{2u-2}-2^{u-1}}{3^u2^u}$$$$=\dfrac18\sum_{u\geq1}\dfrac{2^u}{3^u}-\dfrac14\sum_{u\geq1}\dfrac{2^{u-1}}{3^u}$$$$=\dfrac14-\dfrac12$$$$=-\dfrac14$$

---

---

##### $$\text{My question}$$

---

---

Is my evaluation correct, or what could I do to evaluate it/evaluate it more quickly?

---

---

###### $$\text{Mistakes I might have made}$$

---

---

1. Evaluating it incorrectly
2. Representing it as sums incorrectly
3. Incorrect [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) on the question

Comment: If I recall correctly, it's been already asked

Comment: @SineoftheTime You might be right (I'll try to find it on Approach $0$)

Comment: notice that $\lfloor{x}\rfloor \neq x-1$

Comment: @Zima Ah okay I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @SineoftheTime I wasn't able to find a question that asked this same exact question using Approach $0$, you might be able to find a possible dupe more easily though :\

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4642139/1118406